# ejbFacade is null

Tags: jsf, ejb, managed-bean

I call the managedBean OverzichtAlle.java from the jsf page overzichtAlleGroepen.xhtml

But when I get on this page i get the errormessage can't instantiate managedBeans.OverzichtAlle due to a Nullpointerexception...

When I debug, I see that my ejbFacade is null..

this is the EJB

```
@EJB private ProjecttypeEFacade ejbFacade;
```

and this is my constructor:

```
public OverzichtAlle() 
{
    projE = ejbFacade.findAll();
    omvormenProjectTypes();
}
```

projE is a List (entity-list)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@EJB`s are injected *after* bean's construction. It's for the EJB injection manager namely not possible to call a bean setter method before constructing it:

```
overzichtAlle.setEjbFacade(ejbFacade);
OverzichtAlle overzichtAlle = new OverzichtAlle();
```

Instead, the following is happening behind the scenes:

```
OverzichtAlle overzichtAlle = new OverzichtAlle();
overzichtAlle.setEjbFacade(ejbFacade);
```

So the `ejbFacade` is **not** available inside bean's constructor. The normal approach is to use a [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method for this.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    projE = ejbFacade.findAll();
    omvormenProjectTypes();
}
```

A `@PostConstruct` method is called *directly after* bean's construction and all managed property and dependency injections. You can do your EJB-dependent initializing job in there. The following will then happen behind the scenes:

```
OverzichtAlle overzichtAlle = new OverzichtAlle();
overzichtAlle.setEjbFacade(ejbFacade);
overzichtAlle.init();
```

Note that the method name doesn't matter. But `init()` is pretty self-documenting.