# Javascript Variable Value Get From ManagedBean Property

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a ManagedBean with a property which gets its value from an EJB. In the JSF, I have a Javascript variable which then gets its value from the ManagedBean property. When I run the project, the Javascript variable is not set.

In the ManagedBean, I tried the below methods but doesn't work:

- setting the property's value in the `Constructor`
- setting the property's value in an `init()` method with the `@PostConstruct` annotation
- setting it in the `getMenuData()` method.

**JSF JavaScript**

```
<script>
    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function ()) {
        // Data to build the menubar
        var menuData = [#{userMenu.menuData}];

        ...
    });
</script>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
package com.qrra.PROFIT.web;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import qrcom.profit.ejb.UserMenuFacade;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserMenuController {

    public UserMenuController() {
        menuData = usermenu.buildMenuDataByUserProfile("UAT");
    }

    // @PostConstruct
    // public void init() {
    //    menuData = usermenu.buildMenuDataByUserProfile("UAT");
    // }

    public void getMenuData() {
        return this.menuData;
    }

    public void setMenuData(String menuData) {
        // usermenu.buildMenuDataByUserProfile("UAT");
        this.menuData = menuData;
    }

    private String menuData;
    @EJB
    private UserMenuFacade usermenu;

}
```

When I view source, I only see `var menuData = [];`

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: I prefer to use `h:inputHidden ` for that , like `<h:inputHidden id="someId" value="#{userMenu.menuData}" />` , access it than by its id (might have formId prefix... unless `prependId="false"` is used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor approach would fail because it's [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038919/ejbfacade-is-null/7040771#7040771) to inject an EJB in the instance before the instance is constructed, you'd only face a `NullPointerException` as the EJB is `null`. The `@PostConstruct` approach should work fine. The business-logic-in-getter approach will also work fine, but it is [plain bad design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062).

Provided that you're properly preforming the job in the `@PostConstruct`, your code looks fine. Your concrete problem suggests that `usermenu.buildMenuDataByUserProfile("UAT");` just returns an empty string by itself and thus your concrete problem needs to be solved at higher level. You should already have determined it by yourself with help of a debugger and common sense.

Comment: I tried again using the `@PostConstruct` annotation and launched the debugger and found out where the problem was. A bug in the EJB method. I was focusing on the wrong side of the problem.